# How to adjust the margin for word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have an assignment that is asking me to do a Title page. It wants the 1st line written at 2"center from top, 2nd line at 5" center from top and 4th line 9" from top. I can get the 1st line margin to 2" but every time I do 2nd or 3rd line it creates a new page or moves the 1st line to the new setting. How do I adjust the margins for the 2nd and 4th lines?

Answer (score 1):

Go to page layout on the menu bar and select margins then customize the size that you want.

Here is a [process](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-page-margins-HA102350538.aspx) on how to by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Margins are margins. You are actually moving the same margin each time. There aren't multiple margins from the top.

You will have to use a cover page with a table in it. You can use one from the `Insert` ribbon or create your own on a blank page. Set the table properties to accomplish the dimensions and orientation you need.

[image]